# Sudden stop detection of wirless network

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I am using Atheros AR5007EG wireless Network Adapter, which has suddenly stopped detecting any of the wirless networks available whether at home or at office.. But through LAN I can access Internet..

I have installed updated adapter but then also this problem is unsolved.. anyone here can help me to solve this problem How to establish connection so that I can use wifi software..

OS - Windows XP SP3

in cmd prompt when I have used ipconfig then, it showed Windows IP Configuration- was fine for local connection but message is shown for wireless connection below:

Media stated .................................... Media Discontected

Comment: So what exactly happens when you try to detect wireless networks? Do you get a blank window with no detected networks? Do you get an error?

Comment: yes blank window when I try to detect wirless networks